# Overload "->*" operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, member

I have gone through operator overloading tutorial. I haven't find any example of overloading "->*". It has been told that the mentioned operator is rare and used mostly in expression template.

Can someone enlighten with the details of overloading the operator "->*"?

Comment: there's no such operator.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That's what I thought initially, but then realised that `a->*b` is for calling a member function on `a` through a member-function-pointer `b`.

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators

and here: http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf

```
R &K::operator ->*(S b);

R &operator ->*(K a, S b);
```

Comment: Thanks ten four, I have already gone through with the first link, but the second list is very helpful.